# How to calculate resistance, inductance, capacitor value for dc-dc buck-boost converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, solar-cell, matlab, mppt

How to calculate resistance, inductance, capacitor value for dc-dc buck-boost converter when using  with Solar panel? I am working on a project. Charging battery with solar panel with/ without  MPPT. I am doing this simulation on MATLAB with Simscape Power Systems and Electronic Library. Which allows me to choose Solar panel (I am using SolarWorld SW220 mono Pmax=220w, Vmax= 29.3V, Imax=7.51A) and Battery( lead acid 24V, 16Ah). Also, I need to calculate the efficiency of each case. However, I don't know how to monitor battery charging in MATLAB. 
I tried to reach tutors online but could find anyone who had knowledge on this subject. If anyone can suggest equation, tutor,website, please, comment!

Comment: Read the datasheet for your chosen buck-boost device?

Comment: didn't choose buck-boost device, it is simulation so I need to create myself (give values).

Comment: So how are you boosting (or dropping) the voltage then? There must be some active component in your circuit to do it - what is it?

Comment: Right now it sounds like you are asking about calculating fuel consumption for a car by specifying the fuel octane and the tyre pressure without even knowing what the engine is.

Answer (score 1):

Join TI's Webench: http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/analog/webench/overview.page

The WEBENCH Power Designer will show you various components to use, allow you to set all the parameters and even show costs involved. While obviously they use TI active components, you will learn enough to be able to translate to any components you might select. By looking at their design in Webench and then reading the datasheets you can learn a lot.

Comment: Webbench has to be one of the most useful engineering tools ever created. I use it all the time.